# Why does not show image from DB?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to show my image and title from DB but only title is showing. Why does not show image?

Here is my code:

```
   @foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr>
        
            <td>
                <img src="{{$post->image}}" width="400px" height="300px" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$post->title}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

**My controller:**

```
return view('posts.index')->with('posts',Post::all());
```

Comment: You have a tool called Die and Dump, You can use it by calling `dd(Post::all());` before you return a view, This will show you all the data you are returning in a json format. so add that line before your return and you can see if that property is even in your post object

Answer (score 0):

the answer depend to how you insert the image in database and the location of the image

for example lets say you put image like this

```
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = time() . rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
    $destinationPath = public_path() ;
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    Post::create(['image'=> $fileName, 'title' =>  'example']);
```

in this case you can show image like this

```
    <img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}" width="400px" height="300px" alt="">
```